# If file size equals this goto this else goto that

Tags: batch-file, if-statement

I have a batch file that renames a DLL file from `C:\Program Files\directory\file.dll` to `C:\Program Files\directory\file.dll.orig` by using the "move" command which works perfectly fine.
The next part of the batch file copies a new version of `file.dll` from a network location to `C:\Program Files\directory\` by using the "copy" command which also works perfectly fine.
I have this script which runs as a GPO which also works fine.

The original DLL file is 38,892 KB, the DLL file getting copied from the network location is 38,856 KB.
I don't want this file to get replaced every time a user reboots their computer.  I want to modify the script so it checks to see if the DLL file in the `C:\Program Files\directory\` location is either 38,892 KB and if it is it will copy the new DLL file to that location but if it is 38,856 KB it will exit the script.
How can I put an if statement into the batch file to check for this?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
for %%A in ("C:\Program Files\directory\file.dll") do if "%%~zA"=="38892" goto :NewIsInstalled
rem ... OK, now we know the installed DLL is not the expected size so copy in the right one.
```

--- Or ---

```
for %%A in ("C:\Program Files\directory\file.dll") do call :CheckIt "%%~fA"
goto :EOF

:CheckIt
if "%~z1"=="38892" goto :NewIsInstalled
if "%~z1"=="38856" goto :OldIsInstalled
goto :SomethingElseHappened
```

See the help for "for" and "call" to understand "%~z1".

Comment: You have a mix of %% and % for batch file use and command line use.  It won't work in either as it stands.

Answer (score 0):

Or use this as the first lines: Note that the filesize is in bytes.

```
@echo off
for %%A in ("C:\Program Files\directory\file.dll") do if "%%~zA"=="38856" goto :EOF
```